# show tab-content on button click is not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button group with two buttons using bootstrap. When button "Link 1" is clicked I want to show the tab with id "link1" and when the button "Link 2" is clicked I want to show the tab with id "link2". But its not working, do you know where is the error?

```
<div class="tab-pane clearfix fade" id="links" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
  <div class="btn-group d-flex justify-content-center mb-3" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="#link1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
    Link 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#link2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Link 2 </button>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content bg-white" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active clearfix" id="link1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
      item of link 1
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active clearfix" id="link2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
      item of link 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're going to run into issues with how Bootstrap applies `active` to `btn` elements; essentially once a button is active that state isn't removed, so once you click on (for example) `#link2` clicking to show `#link1` won't result in the active state swapping.  Do you *need* these to be buttons, because `nav-pill` would provide a very similar output.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if its possible to have the navs next to each other without any margin? Like the group of buttons.

Comment: You would need to apply custom styling for that.  The moment you invoke `btn-group` the `active` state problem affects your tabs.